# Rails Fullcalendar IE won't refetchevents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm using the gem fullcalendar-rails.

I'm using ajax for the data and a modal for the event input.

After the event modal has added the new record, I use the fullcalendar `refectchevents` to show the new event on the calendar.  This works in every browser I've tested except IE 9.

Here is the code:

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar
    ignoreTimezone: true,
    editable: true,
    defaultView: 'month',
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 30,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: false,

    select: (start, end, allDay) ->
      title = $("#title")
      description = $("#description")
      hours = $("#hours")
      workorder = $("#workorder_id")
      actcode = $("#actcode_id")
      $("#dialog-form").dialog
        autoOpen: true
        height: 500
        width: 400
        modal: true
        buttons:
          "Create Labor": ->
           $.create "/events/",
             event:
                workorder_id: workorder.val(),
                actcode_id: actcode.val(),
                title: title.val(),
                description: description.val(),
                hours: hours.val(),
                starts_at: "" + start,
                ends_at: "" + end,
                all_day: allDay,
                maxsynch: "N",
                employee_id: $('#calendar').data('employeeid'),
                overtime: "TRUE" if $("#overtime").is(":checked")
            $(this).dialog "close"
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
```

UPDATE1

I changed the following - but, it didn't fix it.

```
   eventSources: [{
     url: '/events',
     cache: false,
   }],
```

UPDATE2

This worked:

```
...
  employee_id: $('#calendar').data('employeeid'),
  overtime: "TRUE" if $("#overtime").is(":checked")
complete: ->
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar problem but i haven't used fullcalendar with rails.

IE caches the data So each time you call refetch events it shows cached events.

I have used events_function to fetch events.
In that I set cache: false  option in ajax request to get events.
It worked in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  What does your events_function code look like?

Comment: I'm using json and here is a quote from fullcalendar `The _ parameter is automatically inserted to prevent the browser from caching the result (more below).`

Comment: I used the following and it worked: `              complete: ->
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')